# Why does the author emphasizes the fact that operator[] cannot return 0?

Tags: c++

The code below was copied from Bruce Eckel's Thinking in C++ Volume 2 Chapter 16

```
//: C07:Wrapped.cpp
// From Thinking in C++, 2nd Edition
// Available at http://www.BruceEckel.com
// (c) Bruce Eckel 2000
// Copyright notice in Copyright.txt
// Safe, atomic pointers

#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
ofstream out("wrapped.out");

// Simplified. Yours may have other arguments.
template<class T, int sz = 1> class PWrap
{
    T* ptr;

    public:
    class RangeError {}; // Exception class
    PWrap() { ptr = new T[sz]; out << "PWrap constructor" << endl; }
    ~PWrap() { delete []ptr; out << "PWrap destructor" << endl; }
    T& operator[](int i) throw(RangeError)
    {
        if(i >= 0 && i < sz) return ptr[i];
        throw RangeError();
    }
};

class Cat
{
    public:
    Cat() { out << "Cat()" << endl; }
    ~Cat() { out << "~Cat()" << endl; }
    void g() {}
};

class Dog
{
    public:
    void* operator new[](size_t sz) { out << "allocating a Dog" << endl; throw int(47); }
    void operator delete[](void* p) { out << "deallocating a Dog" << endl; ::delete p; }
};

class UseResources
{
    PWrap<Cat, 3> Bonk;
    PWrap<Dog> Og;

    public:
    UseResources() : Bonk(), Og() { out << "UseResources()" << endl; }
    ~UseResources() { out << "~UseResources()" << endl; }
    void f() { Bonk[1].g(); }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        UseResources ur;
    }
    catch(int)
    {
        out << "inside handler" << endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        out << "inside catch(...)" << endl;
    }
}
```

**I have no problem with the code itself. But I'm having some trouble understanding the following comment about the class exception `RangeError`:**

"The `PWrap` template shows a more typical use of exceptions than you’ve seen so far: A
nested class called `RangeError` is created to use in `operator[ ]` if its argument is out of range.
Because `operator[ ]` returns a reference it cannot return zero. (There are no null references.)
This is a true exceptional condition – you don’t know what to do in the current context, and
you can’t return an improbable value."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the function were to return a pointer rather than a reference, than it could signal failure (i.e. out-of-bounds index) by returning a `NULL` pointer.  But you can't have `NULL` references, so the only option available is to throw an exception.<sup>*</sup>

As @Steve points out in comments below, you wouldn't want `operator[]` to return a pointer, because that would mean you'd need to write something like:

```
T x = *wrapper[5];
```

---

<sub>* An alternative would be to `assert`.</sub>

Comment: Assuming the operator[] returns a pointer how would you test it for the NULL value ?

Comment: @user1042389: How do you normally test whether a function returns a particular value? Something like `T* ptr = something[i]; if (ptr == 0) { /* it's null */} else { /* it isn't */};`. But it's not very useful for an overloaded `operator[]` to return a pointer, since it doesn't result in the syntax you expect based on the built-in version of the operator.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks Steve. That answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

He emphasizes this to explain why throwing an exception is the only option in this case.

If the operator returned a pointer, it could return a null-pointer instead of throwing an exception in case of errors. But since it returns a reference and there's no such thing as a null-reference the only way to handle errors is to throw an exception.

Comment: Assuming the operator[] returns a pointer how would you test it for the NULL value ?

Comment: @user1042389 If `operator[]` returned a pointer, you could test whether that was null by using `== NULL` on it before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1):

The author explains it pretty well, maybe the zero part is consuming, what he means is that he can not return any value that signifies the lack of value as such (such as null pointer) and therefore throws a fit.

Answer (score 0):

The author has said it "Because operator[ ] returns a reference it cannot return zero.". Because NULL reference is a really bad thing.